# Retrieving sub-element attribute's value based on uniq-key with xslt ant

Tags: xslt, ant

My xml looks something like this:

```
<someRoot
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../my.xsd">

    <position name="quality">

        <db>
            <server name="blah-blah" type="xyz"/>
        </db>

        <some-more-element value="12345"/>

        <my-needy-element>
            <my-needy-sub-element name="uk1"
                  value="a,b,c"
                  more-attr="some-val"/>
            <my-needy-sub-element name="uk2"
                          value="x,b,y,c"
                  more-attr="some-diff-val"/>
         </my-needy-element>

       </position>
</someRoot>
```

Retrieving say my single db-server name works after I do `xmlproperty` & samy something like : ${db.server(name)}. Now I am trying to retrieve value for sub elements - but it always 
gives me all row values matching it. eg: ${my-needy-element.my-needy-sub-element(more-attr)} will print some-val,some-diff-val . How do I get attribute value matching 
to paricular unique name , something like {my-needy-element.my-needy-sub-element(more-attr) with name="uk1"}

Adding editing comment: Is there any way even if I use xslt ant-task by passing 'uk1' & get required sub-element attribute value? with xsl:if or key match

Amending more:

Have tried with xsl & then an xslt ant , but it doesnot seem to give what I am looking for:

```
<xsl:template match="/someRoot/my-needy-element/my-needy-sub-element">

        <someRoot>
                <xsl:key name="my-needy-sub-element" match="text()" use="@name"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('name',$xslParamPassed)"/>
        </someRoot>
    </xsl:template>
```

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with `xmlproperty` but you might consider the third-party [xmltask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) which lets you use full-fledged XPath expressions:

```
<xmltask source="file.xml">
  <copy path="/someRoot/position/my-needy-element/my-needy-sub-element[@name='uk1']/@more-attr"
        property="more.attr" />
</xmltask>
<echo>${more.attr}</echo>
```

Comment: thanks for this. But is there any way even if I use xslt ant-task by passing 'uk1' & get required sub-element attribute value?.